# Converting JSON with arrays to CSV using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I found myself in the world of JSON and I'm trying to convert out of it using `jq`. I'm trying to convert following structure to CSV:

```
{
  "Action": "A1",
  "Group": [
    {
      "Id": "10",
      "Units": [
        "1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Action": "A2",
  "Group": [
    {
      "Id": "11",
      "Units": [
        "2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "20",
      "Units": []
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Action": "A1",
  "Group": [
    {
      "Id": "26",
      "Units": [
        "1",
        "3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Action": "A3",
  "Group": null
}
```

where the Ids are between 10-99 and Units 1-5. Expected output would be (quoted or unquoted, comma separated or not, I used pipe separators for clarity):

```
Action|Group|Unit1|Unit2|Unit3|Unit4|Unit5
A1|10|1|0|0|0|0
A2|11|0|1|0|0|0
A2|20|0|0|0|0|0
A1|26|1|0|1|0|0
A3|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

I've played around with this for a while now (`history | grep jq | wc -l` says 107) but haven't made any real progress to combining the keys with eachother, I'm basically just getting lists of keys (`jq` n00b).

**Update:**

Testing the solution (sorry, been a bit s l o w) I noticed that the data also has records with `"Group": null`s, ie.:

```
{
  "Action": "A3",
  "Group": null
}
```

(above few lines added to the main test data set) which results in error: `jq: error (at file.json:61): Cannot iterate over null (null)`. Expected output would be:

```
A3|0|0|0|0
```

Is there an easy way out of that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general solution if the set of unit columns isn't known in advance:

```
def normalize: [            # convert input to array of flattened objects e.g. 
      inputs                # [{"Action":"A1","Group":"10","Unit1":"1"}, ...]
    | .Action as $a
    | .Group[]
    |   {Action:$a, Group:.Id}
      + reduce .Units[] as $u ({};.["Unit\($u)"]="1")
  ];

def columns:                # compute column names
  [ .[] | keys[] ] | unique ;

def rows($names):           # generate row arrays
    .[] | [ .[$names[]] ] | map( .//"0" );

normalize | columns as $names | $names, rows($names) | join("|")
```

Sample Run (assumes filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mnr -f filter.jq data.json
Action|Group|Unit1|Unit2|Unit3
A1|10|1|0|0
A2|11|0|1|0
A2|20|0|0|0
A1|26|1|0|1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFNU8IwEL33V@wEDu1YAsUZD2U8cHL4AZ5qD7ENTLFNIB8yCP3r4jYpCoo5ZT/e27dv19tTyZdQiY01Og0ADmRemEoKkpJ5QmLypKTdkDQ7kEWJuWSCuWdRGY05kpC8zdsgvkJNb6CSS9QUUXFfmV7y3SC7IWH6cC0hJvdOxsxtIqRqWF198BQyuHgDKKR458r4XcFIYEqxPcglLGtmDBe8BPm65oXRwOmKQuCR3hv49QaQ/aPzx6OkC0gbA6U0d2xHoB4DTMOQnXMOmZ1b8Ai@KR2yGFwtpYuy7fXcgeKlLThQZ0KWOy4L4aGd0cwNfgmHNiL5I06PEJXPgqDzppC1bYRO/@5SyAaX5H0HCNZwjcAMKNIf4Y3vuznd14pqazn0jErudDh07VF6xbhCPxVDSmzxTmun3xN2xB6W5Z63YZsQ6HhMJgQiZA@@D4nFXrhb1KEw5z/xlQRMr2UlQnIk0en0KTedi/o0Gglb1yN3SAwU242kNRh8AQ)

In this specific problem the ordering done by `unique` matches the column output we want.  If that were not the case `columns` would be more complicated.

Much of the complexity comes from dealing with not knowing the final  set of Unit columns.  If the unit set is fixed and reasonably small (e.g. 1-5) a simpler filter can be used:

```
  ["\(1+range(5))"] as $units
| ["Action", "Group", "Unit\($units[])"]
, ( inputs 
  | .Action as $a 
  | .Group[] 
  | [$a, .Id, (.Units[$units[]|[.]] | if .!=[] then "1" else "0" end) ]
) | join("|")
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mnr '["\(1+range(5))"] as $units | ["Action", "Group", "Unit\($units[])"], (inputs | .Action as $a | .Group[] | [$a, .Id, (.Units[$units[]|[.]] | if .!=[] then "1" else "0" end) ] ) | join("|")' data.json
Action|Group|Unit1|Unit2|Unit3|Unit4|Unit5
A1|10|1|0|0|0|0
A2|11|0|1|0|0|0
A2|20|0|0|0|0|0
A1|26|1|0|1|0|0
```

[Try it online at tio.run](https://tio.run/##bZCxbsMgFEV3f8XrUwZQsRW7agdHHTJV@YBOhMGqSerIAsc26hDn10ufsdsmkhkQXO49XDidfakPUJnG9V0eAVxw@9FX1mCO2xQFvrXWNZjLC@5K0tI1ae@m6jvSMEV1VddI3KWyhVR6m8ooJeaT7Ja3AFuokL3cVxD4FGpsPIxD4p6lj21hjpo9c44Kig5WbvTT82Agw4wXMKNpMfL2bLJJRanRK4DRPP0NRIE@QDKlA7X4VwNJqj9BrgoBya4kRhLKyl/4IBOlyFEdIHl4pUj/qQ3QQ0DXnQZc08KUHEIFTsaTrQzDAbn337YZL@98HBtX13HoRpu2@Iqt62nzAw) or at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/WJ85t-ysS3)

---

To handle the case where `Group` may be `null` the easiest way is to use a variation of [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s suggestion.  E.g

```
  ["\(1+range(5))"] as $units
| ["Action", "Group", "Unit\($units[])"]
, ( inputs 
  | .Action as $a 
  | ( .Group // [{Id:"0", Units:[]}] )[]   # <-- supply default group if null
  | [$a, .Id, (.Units[$units[]|[.]] | if .!=[] then "1" else "0" end) ]
) | join("|")
```

[Try it online at tio.run](https://tio.run/##bZC/boMwEMb3PMX1lMFWjVOI2oGqQ6aKB@jkeEDFaYmQofxRB@DVS8@GtImEB8s@f9/P3935a8rMCXJbdW0TbwB6PLy3eWkxxkOIAl/rsqswVj0mGdXCB6q92bxtqIYh6lGPG3HjilZc4bUrIpdYXqJr3gpsJUL0dBtB4H4txv7fabuiGJ8ncEvhkYX3dWo/DHvkHDWkDWw7h6PuYSDBwhCw@OngvjuyWaY0uZxWAKN9Hh1sPH0AObs9Nf2rMulRsNuB6pMsRmobfA@@a670Ram2qQCZZASXXqAuvw5Kak2K/ATy7kVpaD@NBRoAmKIxQEgwNuPgUZyE5zK3DAfk0/RTVi5VMwWBG0bgQ9OlTr@Dsmvp8gs) or [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/59vZhMXYbe)

Comment: You could make it a one-liner if your set of units is known in advance (see amendment at end) but having to deal with the general case makes  the problem tricker.

Comment: Oh? The set of units is known, 1,2,3,4,5. Forgot to mention that, sorry. Ids are also (10-99) but I assume that won't matter.

Comment: Yes that does simplify things.  I've updated the second filter to handle the case of 1-5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. I ran into a null `Group:`, is there an easy fix to that? Please see my update.

Comment: I've added a version of the filter which handles null groups along the lines of [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is for the case where the number of "Unit" columns (n) is known beforehand.  It is just a variant of @jq170717's implementation.

The use of `max` is to ensure reasonable behavior if the given value of `n` is too small.  In that case, the number of columns in the output will vary.

The following has been tested with jq versions 1.5 and master; see below for the tweaks necessary for earlier versions of jq.

Invocation: jq -nr -f tocsv.jq data.json

tocsv.jq:

```
# n is the number of desired "Unit" columns
def tocsv(n):
  def h: ["Action", "Group", "Unit\(range(1;n+1))"];
  def i(n): reduce .[] as $i ([range(0;n)|"0"]; .[$i]="1");
  def p:
    inputs 
    | .Action as $a 
    | .Group[] 
    | [$a, .Id] + (.Units | map(tonumber-1) | i(n));
  h,p | join(",") ;

tocsv(5)
```

The above has been written in a way that you can simply replace the call to `join` by a call to `@csv` or `@tsv` if you want all their benefits.  In that case, though, you might want to use `0` and `1` rather than `"0"` and `"1"` in the indicator function, `i`.

#### Verification

```
$ jq -nr -f tocsv.jq data.json
Action,Group,Unit1,Unit2,Unit3
A1,10,1,0,0
A2,11,0,1,0
A2,20,0,0,0
A1,26,1,0,1
```

#### jq 1.3 or jq 1.4

For jq 1.3 or 1.4, change `inputs` to `.[]`, and use the following incantation:

```
 jq -r -s -f tocsv.jq data.json
```

#### Update

The easiest way to handle the `"Group":null` cases is probably to add the following line immediately before `| .Group[]`:

```
| .Group |= (. // [{Id:"0", Units:[]}])
```

That way you can also easily change the "default" value of "Id".

Comment: @JamesBrown -  I misunderstood the requirements and have made the appropriate revisions (mainly to `def i`).

Comment: @JamesBrown - see also the `Update` section here. It also applies to my other solution.

Comment: Thank you for the update, sir! Now, if I run this solution (`jq --version`: jq-1.5, btw) with parameters `jq -r -s -f ...` I only get the headers but using the original parameters (`jq -nr -f ...`) it seems to work. I'll test it a bit more in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

This is for the case where the number of "Unit" columns (n) is unknown beforehand.  It avoids reading in the entire file at once, and proceeds in three main steps: the relevant information is collected in a compact form by "synopsis"; n is computed; and the full rows are formed.

For simplicity, the following is for jq version 1.5 or later, and uses `@csv`. Small tweaks might be needed if jq 1.4 is used, depending on detailed requirements regarding the output.

#### Invocation

```
jq -nr -f tocsv.jq input.json
```

#### tocsv.jq:

```
# Input: a stream of JSON objects.
# Output: a stream of arrays.
def synopsis:
  inputs 
  | .Action as $a 
  | .Group[] 
  | [$a, .Id, (.Units|map(tonumber-1))];

# Input: an array of arrays
# Output: a stream of arrays suitable for @csv
def stream:
  def h(n): ["Action", "Group", "Unit\(range(1;n+1))"];
  def i(n): reduce .[] as $i ([range(0;n)|0]; .[$i]=1);
  (map(.[2] | max) | max + 1) as $n
  | h($n),
    (.[] | .[0:2] + (.[2] | i($n)))
  ;

[synopsis] | stream | @csv
```

#### Output

```
"Action","Group","Unit1","Unit2","Unit3"
"A1","10",1,0,0
"A2","11",0,1,0
"A2","20",0,0,0
"A1","26",1,0,1
```

#### Update

The easiest way to handle the `"Group":null` cases is probably to add the following line immediately before `| .Group[]`:

```
| .Group |= (. // [{Id:"0", Units:[]}])
```

That way you can also easily change the "default" value of "Id".

Comment: @jq170727 - Ouch! Thanks.

Comment: `def i` has been changed so that the output is as required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with minimal memory requirements for the case where the number of "Unit" columns (n) is unknown beforehand.  In the first pass, n is computed.

#### stream.jq

This is for the second pass:

```
# Output: a stream of arrays.
def synopsis:
  inputs
  | .Action as $a
  | .Group |= (. // [{Id:0, Units:[]}])
  | .Group[] 
  | [$a, .Id, (.Units|map(tonumber-1))];

def h(n): ["Action", "Group", "Unit\(range(1;n+1))"];

# Output: an array suitable for @csv
def stream(n):
  def i: reduce .[] as $i ([range(0;n)|0]; .[$i]=1);
  .[0:2] + (.[2] | i) ;

h($width), (synopsis | stream($width)) | @csv
```

#### Invocation

```
jq -rn --argjson width $(jq -n '
  [inputs|(.Group//[{Units:[]}])[]|.Units|map(tonumber)|max]|max
  ' data.json) -f stream.jq data.json
```

#### Output

This is the output with the "null" record ({"Action": "A3","Group": null}) appended:

```
"Action","Group","Unit1","Unit2","Unit3"
"A1","10",1,0,0
"A2","11",0,1,0
"A2","20",0,0,0
"A1","26",1,0,1
"A3",0,0,0,0
```