# Converting yet another JSON to CSV with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to convert a JSON with nested objects and arrays to a CSV file. The structure is:

```
{
  "Date": {
    "Value": "2017-11-17T00:00:00"
  },
  "ThisOne": false
}
{
  "Date": {
    "Value": "2017-11-17T00:00:00"
  },
  "ThisOne": true,
  "Groups": {
    "10": {
      "Id": "10",
      "SomeUnnecessaryObject": true
    },
    "11": {
      "Id": "11",
      "RequiredObject": {
        "SEeminGlyRANdOMStRiNG": {
          "Value1": "2",
          "Value2": "3",
          "Units": [
            "1",
            "5"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "12": {
      "Id": "12",
      "RequiredObject": {
        "AnOthEr321": {
          "Value1": "1",
          "Value2": "9",
          "Units": [
            "2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(hope I got the parentheses right) and I'm trying to convert it to csv:

```
date|value1|value2|group|unit1|unit2|unit3|unit4|unit5
2017-11-17T00:00:00|2|3|11|1|0|0|0|1
2017-11-17T00:00:00|1|9|12|0|1|0|0|0
```

The groups run from 10 to 99 and units from 1 to 5. The `SEeminGlyRANdOMStRiNG` is a seemingly random string. The objects I want have `RequiredObject` but there are top level objects that don't have it. I've been pruning objects with `select(.ThisOne==true)` because I don't understand how to reference from `.Group ... RequiredObject ... Value1` with changing values in the path. There might be top-level object that have `ThisOne==true` but lack the `RequiredObject`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the same condition on the unit columns [as in your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094953/converting-json-with-arrays-to-csv-using-jq), the following filter should produce the desired output:

```
  ["\(1+range(5))"] as $units
| ["date", "value1", "value2", "group", "unit\($units[])"]
, (
      inputs
    | .Date.Value as $date
    | .Groups[]?
    | .Id as $group
    | .RequiredObject // {}
    | keys[] as $k
    | .[$k]
    | .Value1 as $value1
    | .Value2 as $value2
    | [ $date, $value1, $value2, $group, (.Units[$units[]|[.]] | if .!=[] then "1" else "0" end) ]
  )
| join("|")
```

Sample Run (assumes filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mnr -f filter.jq data.json
date|value1|value2|group|unit1|unit2|unit3|unit4|unit5
2017-11-17T00:00:00|2|3|11|1|0|0|0|1
2017-11-17T00:00:00|1|9|12|0|1|0|0|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBbptAEL37K6ajHEAFwm4URXVVVZEaWTk0luykF8KBhnW8NlkcWFpZNr8eOrsEe6PmkhVCMzvvvXnMsHrucrEAqTaNrscjgB3@yLTA8Q5/ZUVDAfKYXYSMheziNo7H9sE2wNulrKeKAIusqEUbjD7O1FUjApxUZbOpDY/F5n2dE5XCAOflk7hTSjyIus6q7fT3SjzonkYyjB3RjNAz8dzISuQDbIfzK/Ek1aTYzi5v8unPuZ7Jm8nBIDMOiWcTTskZJXdKavKSoFE8x7RtTSd@7MTf7XSppnp5VZ1x9kaeufJfXHlupdv2awf2JHjvsc9Vph6Fd@77mEJWw0lj4CNT3xMiN@MNAP/08kPETfRohmgCQ7n3emaSkpClB@CN4HD6bR8u9hCZzUXWqe1rOrnlfkVJ@t29vM4t1nZ2799OB05PYdc69bXYkpKlrl1acrJO3bwfosX1H/xfkR@L3Ckmvf9g4A0BD17N0jAiu4hkGNM@idKUqHIB0adv5E4vhQJaHwj6twFjClTuw2DQf93JqpTKwz36XfdSbrQsVd2FoWqKIrQzpqTK/oZloyn5Bw)

Comment: btw, what's: `.RequiredObject // {}`?

Comment: `expr // value` means return `value` when `expr` is false or null.  See [Alternative Operator //](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://)

Comment: Also since there's no need for the seemingly random string keys this could be simplified a bit more.  Instead of `| .RequiredObject // {} | keys[] as $k | .[$k]` you could just use `.RequiredObject[]?` letting the [`?`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.[]?) deal with missing RequiredObjects.